# Inline css doesn't work with JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I started working with phonegap so I am new with it. I included JqueryMobile to it. It all works nicely but how do I change the style of for example a text field.
When I use inline css like

```
<input type="text" style="width:30px;" />
```

It doesn't work. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: can you not use external CSS?

Comment: Would that work? I thought inline CSS is used first of all and that you can't change it with external CSS

Comment: your CSS property can be overriden by another CSS rule coming from external CSS. Just use a dev tool as chrome console to check what happen

Comment: And as I feared. I just tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: If it's specific to that text-box only, give it an ID and style that ID using external CSS or jQuery. If you would like change the text-box style universally, just use something like input[type='text'] and style it.

Comment: Post some code please. Use jQuery .CSS method and it will override any inline or external CSS styles.

Comment: For example: for example: http://jsfiddle.net/uf2FV/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not working because you dont need to change input width, that element is hidden in jQuery Mobile. You need to change its wrapper DIV and it can be only done through javascript.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/kSAGf/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $('#custom-input').parent().css('width','30px');    
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works! Couldn't have thought of that in years and I may not have searched enough maybe but I couldn't find it with google either

Comment: Just come here when you need any help, we will gladly help you :)

Comment: Yes stackoverflow has helped me a lot so far! Thanks again!